Why is call trace empty (not shown) in the Linux kernel log?
I've seen few kernel threads being busy on CPU, while there was clearly no work for the driver those threads were spawned by.
To learn more about this weird finding, I ran SysRQ+l (backtrace all active CPUs) a few times and looked in dmesg.
And I found out, they have no Call Trace...
[33281.841479] NMI backtrace for cpu 15
[33281.841481] CPU: 15 UID: 0 PID: 791 Comm: bch-rebalance/n Not tainted 6.12.0 #11
[33281.841488] RIP: 0010:lock_acquire+0x81/0x2d0
[33281.841493] Code: 09 7f 85 c0 0f 85 0c 01 00 00 65 48 8b 05 27 01 0b 7f 8b 88 c4 0e 00 00 85 c9 0f 85 f6 00 00 00 9c 58 0f 1f 40 00 49 89 c3 fa <0f> 1f 44 00 00 41 81 e3 00 02 00 00 45 89 e0 89 d9 4d 89 d9 44 89
[33281.841496] RSP: 0018:ffffc9000bd1f4a0 EFLAGS: 00000046
[33281.841499] RAX: 0000000000000246 RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: 0000000000000000
[33281.841501] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffffffff8518cc40
[33281.841503] RBP: ffffc9000bd1f510 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[33281.841505] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
[33281.841507] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffffff8518cc40 R15: 0000000000000000
[33281.841509] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff888ffea00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[33281.841512] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[33281.841515] CR2: 00007fffd4005048 CR3: 0000000121004001 CR4: 00000000001706f0
[33281.841517] Call Trace:
[33281.841369] NMI backtrace for cpu 10

You can see that after Call Trace: there is nothing and it goes on to another CPU.
I have never seen such thing.
The question is, why and how the Call Trace can be missing in the Linux kernel log? Is it something I should be concerned about? My architecture is x86_64.
